# Parse JSON array output by PHP

Tags: c++, arrays, json, qt

I have a JSON array which PHP returns, example output from PHP:

```
[
  {
    "uid": "1",
    "username": "mike",
    "time_created": "2014-12-27 15:30:03",
    "time_updated": "2014-12-27 15:30:03",
    "time_expires": "2014-12-27 15:30:03"
  },
  {
    "uid": "2",
    "username": "jason",
    "time_created": "2014-12-27 15:31:41",
    "time_updated": "2014-12-27 15:31:41",
    "time_expires": "2014-12-27 15:31:41"
  },
  {
    "uid": "3",
    "username": "david",
    "time_created": "2014-12-27 18:10:53",
    "time_updated": "2014-12-27 18:10:53",
    "time_expires": "2014-12-27 18:10:53"
  }
]
```

I tried several methods, I tried Iterator, I tried toArray from JSonObject, but nothing seems to work!
So far I have this sample code:

```
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(JData.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
for (QJsonObject:: Iterator it = jsonObject.begin(); it != jsonObject.end(); ++it) {
QJsonArray array= (*it).toArray();
foreach (const QJsonValue & v, array)
qDebug() << v.toString();
```

I tried several other ways, no luck. I need to iterate through this JSON data. Please advice. I'm using QT 5.4, C++.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing seems to work"?  Did the code you posted not do what you expected, did it fail to compile, etc. etc.?

Comment: How did it not work? What are the specifics of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just verified your code with putting the data to QString first (not implying it needs to be done, only for my debug). A couple of problems found:

1. An array is on upper level of the document.
2. QJsonValue::toString() could not traverse the nested structure but QJsonValue
   (variable v) still can be printed via qDebug() stream.

---

```
QString JsonStr =
"["
  "{"
    "\"uid\": \"1\","
    "\"username\": \"mike\","
    "\"time_created\": \"2014-12-27 15:30:03\","
    "\"time_updated\": \"2014-12-27 15:30:03\","
    "\"time_expires\": \"2014-12-27 15:30:03\""
  "},"
  "{"
    "\"uid\": \"2\","
    "\"username\": \"jason\","
    "\"time_created\": \"2014-12-27 15:31:41\","
    "\"time_updated\": \"2014-12-27 15:31:41\","
    "\"time_expires\": \"2014-12-27 15:31:41\""
  "},"
  "{"
    "\"uid\": \"3\","
    "\"username\": \"david\","
    "\"time_created\": \"2014-12-27 18:10:53\","
    "\"time_updated\": \"2014-12-27 18:10:53\","
    "\"time_expires\": \"2014-12-27 18:10:53\""
  "}"
"]";

QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(JsonStr.toUtf8());
QJsonArray array = jsonResponse.array();
// print
foreach (const QJsonValue & v, array)
{
    qDebug() << v;
}

// or parse
foreach (const QJsonValue& v, array)
{
    QJsonObject o = v.toObject();
    qDebug() << o["username"];
    qDebug() << o["time_expires"];
}
```